# Volume of a Bounded Solid Region Rotated about $x$-axis

Tags: integration

This is a what I think the area bounded between $y=x^4$ and $y=1$ rotated about $y=4$ looks like in $2D$.
To find its volume, I've also graphed it in $3D$.

Something I've tried: find the volume of the purple and yellow coneish and add the volume of the bluepink cylinder.

Another thing I tried: find the volume of the entire section of $f(x)$ from yellow to purple and minus the sectioned-off volume of $y=1$ minus $f(x)$ from $-1$ to $1$.

What am I missing or is this not a disk method problem?
What are my other options?
[image: 2d]

[image: the area bounded between y=x^4 and y=1 rotated about y=4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use Disk, its close relative Washer, or Shells. Let's use Washer.  I will assume we are rotating about the line $y=4$ (the title says something else).

The line $y=x^4$ meets $y=1$ at $x=\pm 1$.

Take a slice of the solid, perpendicular to the $x$-axis, "at" $x$, where $-1\le x\le 1$.  The cross-section is a disk with radius $4-x^4$, with a circular hole of radius $3$ cut out. Thus the area of cross-section at $x$ is equal to 
$$\pi\left((4-x^4)^2-3^2\right).$$
It follows that the volume is
$$\int_{x=-1}^1 \pi\left((4-x^4)^2-3^2\right)\,dx.$$

Actually, I would prefer to use the symmetry about the $y$-axis of the region we are rotating, integrate from $0$ to $1$, and double the result.

Equivalently, let's rotate the region below $y=4$, above $y=x^4$, from $x=-1$ to $x=1$. We get volume $\int_{-1}^1 \pi(4-x^4)^2\,dx$. Now remove the "hole" which is a cylinder of radius $3$ and height $2$, whose volume can be found without integration.